Why not Poisson distribution?
Question: You usually get 2 phone calls/hour, calculate the probability that a phone call will come within the next hour.
Solution: In the solution, the Exponential distribution is used and the probability is 0.8674.
But why is the answer different when applying the Poisson distribution? I'm getting 0.271 when using it.
Can someone tell me why the Poisson distribution is not applicable here?

This is a Poisson distribution. You can say the probability of getting at least one call is the same as 1 - probability of getting no calls.
So doing the arithmetic:
$$P(k)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$$
$$P(0) =\frac{e^{-2}2^0}{0!}=e^{-2}$$
So your probability is $1-P(0)$, which is $0.8647$.

Yes that is correct

Using the fact that the time of the first phone call is $\text{Exponential}(2)$,
$$P(\text{phone call in next hour}) = P(\text{time of first phone call} < 1) = 1 - e^{-2}\approx 0.8647.$$

Alternatively, using the fact that the number of phone calls within the next hour is $\text{Poisson}(2)$,
$$P(\text{phone call in next hour}) = P(\text{number of phone calls in the next hour} \ge 1) = 1 - P(\text{zero phone calls in the next hour}) = 1 - e^{-2} \approx 0.8647.$$
I think you instead mistakenly computed $$P(\text{number of phone calls in the next hour} = 1) = 2e^{-2} \approx 0.271.$$

Yes you are right I only calculate for exactly 1 phone call.
